# Orientation of a curve in $\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: curves, parametrization, orientation

Let $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^3}, \gamma(t) := (0,0,1)+\cos(t)v_1+\sin(t)v_2$,

where $v_1 =(\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3},-\frac{2}{3}),v_2=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$.

I know this curve is a circle centered at $(0,0,1)$ with radius 1 in the plane spanned by $v_1,v_2$. If it is in $\mathbb{R^2}$, I can calculate the determinant to find the orientation. However, I have no idea if it is in $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Curves do not have orientation in $\mathbb{R}^3$. You can rotate the curve in space and "change its orientation", so it is impossible to distinguish. There is, however, a concept of orientation of a curve in its plane, if the plane is oriented.

Comment: @GReyes Thanks for your clarification. What is the orientation of the curve in its "normal surface"? I don't know anything about oriented plane, can you give me any reference please